# PHP normalize remote url's

Tags: php, html, url, encoding, formatting

Is there any quick function that will convert: `HtTp://www.ExAmPle.com/blah` to  `http://www.example.com/blah`

Basically I want to lower case the case-insensitive parts of a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for "quick," here's a one-liner that does the job:

```
$url = 'HtTp://User:Pass@www.ExAmPle.com:80/Blah';

echo preg_replace_callback(
  '#(^[a-z]+://)(.+@)?([^/]+)(.*)$#i',
  create_function('$m',
                  'return strtolower($m[1]).$m[2].strtolower($m[3]).$m[4];'),
  $url);
```

Outputs:

```
http://User:Pass@www.example.com:80/Blah
```

**EDIT/ADD:**

I've tested, and this version is about 55% faster than using preg_replace_callback with an anonymous function:

```
echo preg_replace(
  '#(^[a-z]+://)(.+@)?([^/]+)(.*)$#ei',
  "strtolower('\\1').'\\2'.strtolower('\\3').'\\4'",
  $url);
```

Comment: This looks more reliable, thanks

Comment: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Answer (score 5):

No, you'll have to write code for it on your own.

But you can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to split the URL into its parts.

Comment: Seems like a sane approach as it gives the developer more control over the process vs. using strtolower, which might butcher case sensitive parts of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this `class` will do what you're looking for http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/01/09/normalize-urls-with-php/

Comment: Looks like an overkill just to do something simple

Comment: Depends if you want it doing quickly or want to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, expanding on what @ThiefMaster already mentioned:

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/SmtU4)**

```
function urltolower($url){
  if (($_url = parse_url($url)) !== false){ // valid url
    $newUrl = strtolower($_url['scheme']) . "://";
    if ($_url['user'] && $_url['pass'])
      $newUrl .= $_url['user'] . ":" . $_url['pass'] . "@";
    $newUrl .= strtolower($_url['host']) . $_url['path'];
    if ($_url['query'])
      $newUrl .= "?" . $_url['query'];
    if ($_url['fragment'])
      $newUrl .= "#" . $_url['fragment'];
    return $newUrl;
  }
  return $url; // could return false if you'd like
}
```

*Note: Not battle-tested but it should get you going.*

Comment: FYI, this will break if there is a user but no pass. Or if user, pass, query or fragment evaluate to zero. And, will raise a warning in any case. Should do "if (isset($var))" instead of "if ($var)" in this instance where those vars may not be set and, if set, may be valid but evaluate to zero.

Comment: Also, it's deleting the port. I won't claim my regex one-liner is bulletproof, but it doesn't have these problems. Good luck.